# Isolated essential singularities and Cauchy's residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I need to evaluate the following integral:

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \frac{e^{-z^2}e^{-i\frac{\alpha}{z-z_1}}}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}
$$
where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are located on the positive imaginary axis. But functions of type $e^{1/z}$ have essential singularities. See for instance the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907193/identify-the-isolated-singularities-of-the-fz-frac-cos1-zz-13-i?rq=1).

Suppose I do the Laurent expansion so that
$$
I=\sum_{n} \left(\frac{i\alpha}{n!}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \frac{e^{-z^2}}{(z-z_1)^{n+1}(z-z_2)}
$$
Given in this form, is there any obstruction to apply Cauchy's residue theorem term by term in the summation ? Is this a legitimate approach ?

Comment: Well, the function in your integral only has an **isolated essential singularity**, not a non-isolated singularity.

Comment: Ah..I see so Cauchy's theorem still apply. Right ?